# Testing Performance in Dart

Tags: javascript, performance, unit-testing, testing, dart

I have done loads of research into performance testing, (test before you optimize they said, it will be fun they said...) and I've realized that testing in languages like C++ or C# is childs play compared to dart with its multiple levels of optimizations and strange quirks (the print functions displaying additional data affected my stopwatch even when placed after the actual stopwatch print)

so this is an question of many questions all completely answerable:

1. there must be some sort of add-on or plugin that was made for testing, if this is true where can I get in on that?(I do not mean the Unit-Test class, my stuff works as intended...)
2. is there a place/site/page/book where Java script and Dart is being compared as to debunk obvious misconceptions? (e.g do I recreate the object, or modify the fields?)
3. does Dart even make it to the cache? I know everything does... but without structs there really isn't much of a stack...

I'm hoping I can get someone to point me in a decent direction(or even some good answers) when it comes to these questions...

Comment: Do you know about Observatory, the Dart profiler ? It offers quite some features. (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the benchmark_harness library https://www.dartlang.org/articles/benchmarking/
2. I guess this is too early. For Dart a lot of optimization work is done. As long as this hasn't settled answers to these questions might get stale quick.
3. You should post a link to this question at https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/compiler-dev

Comment: I guess this answer will suffice, as we don't want to start a discussion here, thanks, I'll check all these locations